# Calculate probability density mean python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, probability-density

Let's say I have a heatmap of probability density function as a `numpy ndarray(m,n)`. Is there a function that automatically computes mean treating this matrix as probability density? I can't seem to find a function that would automatically do that.

Of course an easy solution would be to create a weighted average with weights equal to indices of the array, but seems like there should be a built-in function that would just do that.

Clasification: 
Say my array is `heatmap = [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1.5,0],[0,0,0,0]]`. 
No if we assume that this is not normalized probability you can calculate mean and other properties of the probability density.

For example mean in x direction would be

```
    xx = np.arange(0,heatmap.shape[1],1)
    weights = np.tile(xx,(heatmap.shape[0],1))

    mean_x = np.average(weights, weights = heatmap_avg_left)
```

I'm just looking for a function in numpy or scipy that would do this and other probability properties automatically

Comment: Could you clarify your question to show a minimal example of your array and what mean you would expect?

Comment: are you looking for something like the 50th percentile of the data in each direction, or the center of mass?

Comment: Just added a clarification. Yeah sort of like center of mass treating the array as probability density.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense to someone not living in your head. Please post a complete example.

Comment: Please fix your code to use variables that are defined...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the center-of-mass of an array using [`scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.center_of_mass.html). If your array is indexed into a map containing the individual masses, you can transform directly:

```
from scipy.ndimage import center_of_mass

indices = ... # shape (m, n), values in [0, k)
mass_lookup = ... # shape (k)

result = center_of_mass(mass_lookup[indices])
```

In this case, `mass_lookup` is like a heat map. If the array contains weights instead, use it directly.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between a heat map and an array of weights?

Comment: @Stef. I'm describing a situation where the integer label in the array corresponds to an index into `mass_lookup`, which is a simple lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

```
# assuming the array is called pdf_arr
axis = 0  # 0 for x axis (columns), 1 for y axis (rows)
marginal_pdf = pdf_arr.sum(axis=axis)
# since it's just a sample, normalize pdf
marginal_pdf /= marginal_pdf.sum()
axis_mean = (marginal_pdf * np.arange(pdf_arr.shape[1-axis])).sum()
# repeat the same for axis = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this would work. I was just hoping there would be a built-in function for working with probability densities.